# How to skip a part of an animation?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I have a view initially located at position **A** ,  and two other positions named **B** and **C**.
This image shows the initial state of the view.

[image]

What I want to achieve is to animate the view from **B** to **C**, **but in a different way.**

I want the animation object to start from **A** and finishes at **C** but skips the **A→B** part, performing only the **B→C** part.

The code should look like this :

```swift
// aLabel and cLabel are the labels shown in the image above
let a = aLabel.center.x
let c = cLabel.center.x

let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
animation.duration = 3

// The animation should start in code from A
animation.fromValue = a

// And ends at C
animation.toValue = c

// Update the model layer
someView.layer.position.x = c

/* ADD SOMETHING TO MAKE THE ANIMATION 
STARTS FROM B AND ENDS AT C */
```

### What I've already tried

I tried to set the animation offset to 1.5 :

```
animation.timeOffset = 1.5
```

But It didn't work. The animation executes as following:
**B → C → A → B** , I only want **B → C**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To jump the **A→B** part, you can set the `fromValue` to bLabel center.

```
animation.fromValue = bLabel.center.x
```

if you want to keep the `fromValue` and `toValue` set the `repeatDuration` along with `timeOffset`:

```
    animation.timeOffset = 1.5
    animation.repeatDuration = 1.5
```

Comment: I'm sorry but for some reasons, I cannot change the animation's fromValue and toValue. I need another approach, I mentioned in the question that I need a different way.

Comment: @SalimBraksa I edited my answer, check if the edit answers your question.